# Why is if condition now working with now()

Tags: formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to work with an if condition with now() but it doesn't work no matter the `now()` is more or less than the fix `time()`. what can be the reason?

```
=IF(NOW()>TIME(9,25,0),"No Records","ABSENT")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(MOD(NOW(), 1) > TIME(9, 25, 0), "No Records", "ABSENT")
```

Date time is a numeric value internally. Time part is decimal part, so `MOD(..., 1)` gives you the time part as it gives the remainder for the division by 1.